# Best Practices exposing Bower components

Tags: bower

I am building a Spring project with Bower to manage client libraries. I am interested to know what is the best practices way to expose those libraries (or any sort of client libraries managed by a package manager) to the web client.

I can see that I can use a .bowerrc file to choose where to install the files. I could have them install into a static resources folder, one where each of the files installed would be accessible to http requests. It struck me as a potential code smell, however, to expose all the files, instead of the ones that I specifically need.

I could copy individual files into such a directory, or adopt an automated solution to do the same. If this is not considered necessary, however, I would prefer not to expend the effort.

Which of these, or any other solution (if any) is considered the clear best practices way to do this and why? (Please provide a reference to support your answer.) To be clear, I am not interested in individual opinion, but rather if there is a known, clearly preferred, solution.

Comment: well, at least I got the "tumbleweed" badge out of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at what a lot of projects and tutorial suggest, it seems that the clear way to do this is the following:

Use a framework like Grunt or Gulp to separate "built" code from source code. Built code, in this case refers to code that is copied, minified, and/or concatenated into a separate folder. The Grunt or Gulp configuration file should include all application code, as well as select source files from bower components. The running application should reference only these "built" files. The directory of "built" client-side code should be served statically by Spring.